# P2Pool Missing BTC Reward in Block History

Tags: block, mining-reward, p2pool

I have been studying the block history for P2Pool here:

http://p2pool.org/stats/?blockoffset=40

over the last several days.  I noticed that bitcoin reward for each recent block is blank until 459871 and previous blocks (which appears after scrolling through several pages of block history).  Once you get to block 459871, it shows mining rewards as I'd expect.  Can someone help me understand why this is?  I have been mining on the site for quite some time with some S9s and still haven't received a reward.  I'm wondering if this might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a message being displayed on the P2Pool site that reads, "January 25, 2018: Our historical block data became corrupted (only relating to it's display on this website), data for all blocks after April 1st, 2017 were lost. They will be restored to the data set ASAP." so this is the reason for the missing information.